# IOS application file size

Tags: ios, bitcode

My task is to compare the size of source code build and app store deployed app(both are sane app).

I have generated IPA file of the source code build in MAC.
Its file size is `29 mb.`

In app store the size of the same application is `67 mb`.

**How do i compare the size of both?**

Comment: 67 mb - 29mb its pretty simple subtraction.

Comment: bitcode disable then check

Answer (score 0):

Check Project Settings.

I guess that it has something to do with **bitcode** `(actually disabled)` and application thinning).

check whether they are the same (something like arm64, armv7 & arm7s). The more you offered in VALID_ARCHS, a bigger ipa will be got after you archived.

1) ARMv8/ARM64: iPhone 6, iPhone 5s, iPad Air, Retina iPad Mini

2) ARMv7s: iPhone 5, iPhone 5c, iPad 4

3) ARMv7: iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4, iPhone 4S, iPod 3G/4G/5G, iPad, iPad 2, iPad 3, iPad Mini

4) ARMv6: iPhone, iPhone 3G, iPod 1G/2G